# Understanding REGEX expression with groups in SQL query

Tags: sql, regex, string

I am currently debugging an old script and trying to understand a regex in an SQL query.

What would be the result of this search?

```
[...] REGEXP '(^| |"|\\()ORDER(-| )[[:digit:]]{3}';
```

Comment: It's the same as `(^|[ "(])ORDER[- ]\d{3}`; It's matching any string that either starts with ORDER or contains the word ORDER after a space, `"` or `(`; and is followed by either `-` or a space and then 3 digits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a part by part explanation:

- `(^| |"|\\()`: either the beginning of the string (`^`), or a space, or a double quote, or an opening parenthese (this character needs to be escaped because it is meaningful in regexes)
- `ORDER`: the word "ORDER"
- `(-| )`: either a dash or a space
- `[[:digit:]]{3}`: a sequence of 3 consecutive digits (between 0 and 9)

Comment: Please elaborate on the anonymous downvote: what is wrong with this accepted answer?